# Using "include" directive gives error, How to include source code from external file

Tags: python, include, quarto

- If I include the simple python file I get error message with `quarto render outer.qmd`.
- If I merge the lines from the included file, There is no error with `quarto render outer-merged.qmd`.

[The quarto doc states explicitely](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/includes.html);:

> A very important thing to understand about includes is that they are equivalent to copying and pasting the text from the included file into the main file.

So, if I haven't a fundamental misunderstanding... What's going on here?

*Note: I am using quarto 1.2.313, latest current release, also checked with current head release 1.3.124*

Thanks for any help, Christoph

**Error message with `quarto render outer.qmd`**

```
Starting python3 kernel...Done

Executing 'outer.ipynb'
  Cell 1/1...ERROR: 

An error occurred while executing the following cell:
------------------

{{< include inner.py >}}
------------------

  Cell In [1], line 1
    {{< include inner.py >}}
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

SyntaxError: invalid syntax (2193102924.py, line 1)
```

**outer.qmd**

````
---
title: "test"
format:
  html:
    code-fold: true
jupyter: python3
---

Some text.

```{python}
#| label: fig-test
#| fig-cap: "test"

{{< include inner.py >}}

```
````

**inner.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print( "inner" )
```

**outer-merged.qmd**

````
---
title: "test"
format:
  html:
    code-fold: true
jupyter: python3
---

Some text.

```{python}
#| label: fig-test
#| fig-cap: "test"

#!/usr/bin/python3

print( "inner" )
```
````

Comment: You are using includes inside the code chunk, and jupyter kernel is trying to parse the syntax of that include and since it is not a valid python syntax, you are getting the error.

Comment: Thanks! I understand.

So there seems to be no way to include a python executable script, that is executed and rendered in a quarto markdown document?

ps: can't vote you up - not enough karma yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Includes](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/includes.html) inside the code chunk, and Jupyter kernel is trying to parse the syntax of that include and since it is not a valid python syntax, you are getting the python SyntaxError.

Now if you want to include source code from External Scripts like `inner.py`, a possible option could be using the Quarto Extension filter [`include-code-files`](https://github.com/quarto-ext/include-code-files) ("Installation" process and "how to use" are in the repo readme).

Now using that filter only includes the code from the External script file, doesn't execute it (as per my knowledge) and so if you want to execute the code from `inner.py`, a possible approach could be using Jupyter magic [`%run`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#line-magics). So We could do the following,

**outer.qmd**

````
---
title: "Including Code"
format:
  html:
    code-fold: true
jupyter: python3
filters: 
  - include-code-files
---

## Python

Some text in `outer.qmd`.

```{.python include="inner.py"}
```

```{python}
#| echo: false
%run inner.py
```
````

(Here `echo: false` is used, so that %run inner.py is not visible in the rendered output)

**inner.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print("Hello from inner")

for name in ["Sam", "Jake"]:
    print(f"Hello {name}!")
```

**output**

[image: html output]

---

The major flaw of this proposed solution is that, the `code-fold: true` is not working for the `.python` chunk with `include`.

Comment: Thank you again, shafee! Your proposed solution looks quite good.

Comment: @gcl, does this answer solve your problem? :)

Comment: It is 90% of a solution, so quite good. In fact i do not want see the code in the rendered output at all, only the result of the execution of the code (which works). I tried a global "echo:false" which works with "normal" embedded code, but for the ".python include"d code a grey box remains.

Comment: got it - hiding the source code was easy with a small piece of css.

    format:
      html:
        code-fold: true
        css: styles.css


and "styles.css":

    div[class="sourceCode"]
    {
        display: none
    }